# Open a new scene after video playback

Tags: android, andengine

I am learning android and I am trying to figure out how to open a new scene adfter a video view has finished.

This is my code:

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class SplashScene extends Activity implements OnCompletionListener {

    BaseActivity activity;
    VideoView video;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.vvSplashVideo);
        String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName()
                + "/raw/splashscreen";
        video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));

        video.setOnCompletionListener(this);

        video.start();
        loadResources();
    }

    public void loadResources() {


    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        Log.v("Fin", "done");

        activity.setCurrentScene(new MainMenuScene());      
    }
```

When I run the app, the video works and the log message works but then I get this error:

http://puu.sh/1YuiA before the app crashes.

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you have to initialize `activity;`inside SplashScene  class.

code:

```
public class SplashScene extends Activity implements OnCompletionListener {

BaseActivity activity;
....

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

activity=new BaseActivity (); <===== initiate this

// rest of code }
```

}

}